# How to serialize a date string from JSON to java.util.date?

Tags: retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2 as a REST client for my project. I am having issues with converting date strings in JSON responses to Java `java.util.Date` objects. The response that I am getting from the API is of the following format:

```
[
  {
    "id": "2",
    "date": "2017-04-26",
    "description": "test",
    "created_at": "2017-04-26 05:54:27",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-26 05:54:27"
  }
]
```

I want to convert the `date` value to a `java.util.Date` object. How can I do the conversion? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Retrofit is not responsible for message deserialization. If you're using Gson, then you can refer this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650913/gson-deserializer-for-java-util-date

Comment: FYI, the `Date` class is now legacy, avoid it. Supplanted by the java.time classes.  `LocalDateTime.parse( "2017-04-26 05:54:27".replace( " " , "T" ) )`